# How would I relay/proxy/mirror RADIUS from one server to another?

Tags: networking, radius

Scenario...

I have a Windows Server 2003 box acting as a RADIUS server that is connected to my AD in network A.

I have network B which is not connected to network A.

Can I install something on a box in network B that would relay RADIUS traffic over a VPN connection to the RADIUS server on network A?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay w/ a COTS solution the [Network Policy Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732054(WS.10).aspx) in Windows Server 2008 can function as a RADIUS proxy (though I have no experience actually using it for this). That may be a little more than you want to spend on a box for this purpose, but that's an option. A Microsoft VPN between the "network B" host and "network A" is a viable option for a VPN between the two.

On the open source front, the FreeRADIUS project can [act as a RADIUS proxy](http://wiki.freeradius.org/Proxy). You could use something like OpenVPN to do a VPN between a machine on "network B" running FreeRADIUS in proxy mode and a host (even the Windwos Server 2003 machine hosting RADIUS, if you wanted) on "network A". That's more a "you get to build it yourself" solution, but if you've got an excess of time and a deficit of money that might also be a way to go.